# Как добавить прокрутку столбца ColumnDefinition?

Tags: wpf

Нужна прокрутка столбца Name="col2"

Так неработает.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col2"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
            <!-- сюда помещаете элементы колонки col2 -->
        </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer/>
```